# MySQL installer 5.6.49 - installation error

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm trying to install MySQL on windows 7 32- bit system, At the last step while applying configuration it says **"The Configuration of MySQL server 5.6.49 has failed".**

i have attached an [image of log tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPv0O.png).

how can i resolve this?

Comment: Check that .Net Framework 4.x is installed correctly. Upgrade it to the most recent version. Or reinstall this assembly separately from http : / / go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727&clcid=0x804 *on windows 32- bit system* - precise version?

Comment: windows 7. Also i have the recent version installed.

Comment: Win7 and mysql 5.6 are both a bit elderly now.

Comment: yes I understand. so I tried with recent MySQL version that is 8.0.21 but the server isn't even listed in the options.